# Cannot bind parameter 'Replace' to the target. Exception setting "Replace" : "Object Reference

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Find all accounts with a Department
# Copy that value into Description
Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties telephoneNumber, otherTelephone, facsimileTelephoneNumber, otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber, mobile, otherMobile | 
Select-Object * | 
ForEach-Object {Set-ADObject -Identity $_.DistinguishedName `
-Replace @{otherTelephone=$($_.telephoneNumber);otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber=$($_.facsimileTelephoneNumber);otherMobile=$($_.mobile)}}
```

The problem is, that some users don't have a mobile phone number or facsimile Number. For these users I receive the following error message:

> Set-ADObject : Der Parameter "Replace" kann nicht an das Ziel gebunden
>   werden. Ausnahme beim Festlegen von "Replace": " Der Objektverweis
>   wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt." Bei
>   C:\Scripts\Set_AD_Phone.ps1:8 Zeichen:9
>   + -Replace <<<<  @{otherTelephone=$($*.telephoneNumber);otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber=$($*.facsimileTelephoneNumber);ot
>   herMobile=$($_.mobile)}}
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-ADObject], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADObject

I cannot see any error at the script. does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `Select *` in your command is obsolete. Also you don't have to use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, just pipe the result of `Get-ADUser` to the `Set-ADObject` cmdlet and omit the `-Identity` parameter:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity rzhrzzim -Properties DistinguishedName, telephoneNumber, otherTelephone, facsimileTelephoneNumber, otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber, mobile, otherMobile | 
    Set-ADObject -Replace @{otherTelephone=$_.telephoneNumber;otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber=$_.facsimileTelephoneNumber;otherMobile=$_.mobile}
```

Comment: Yes right. But i want to run the script later for all users. Then is have to use the Select and the the ForEach-Object:

Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties telephoneNumber, otherTelephone, facsimileTelephoneNumber, otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber, mobile, otherMobile|

Comment: I doubt you need that.

Comment: I think I found the reason for the error messages: The problem is, that some users don't have a mobile phone number or facsimile Number. For these users I receive the error messages. But I don't know how to handle this. :(